# How to set selected values of Select2 while using AJAX Data with laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, tags, jquery-select2

**Controller@Update**

```
  //Update
  $course = Course::findOrFail($id);
  $course->name = Input::get('name');
  $course->code = Input::get('code');
  $course->credits = Input::get('credits');
  $course->description = Input::get('description');

  $course->tags()->sync(Input::get('tags')); // Use of sync method

  //return [$course];
  $course->save();
  //Redirect
  Session::flash('message', 'Successfully edited the course : '.$course->name);
  return $this->show($course->code);
```

**HTML**

```
<pre>
<div class="form-group">
     {{Form::label('tags', 'Tag')}}
     {{Form::select('tags[]',[],null,array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'tags[]','id'=>'tag_list','class'=>'form-control'))}}
   </div>
</pre>
```

**Select2 script**

```
function tagResultTemplater(tag) {
    return tag.name + " : " + tag.type;
  }

  function tagSelectionTemplater(tag) {
    return tag.id + " "+tag.name + " : " + tag.type;
  }
  $("#tag_list").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "{!! route('tags.json') !!}",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      tags: true,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    placeholder: function(){
      $(this).data('placeholder');
    },
    templateResult: tagResultTemplater,
    templateSelection: tagSelectionTemplater

  });
```

I'm working on course management system as a grad project, in short there is a many to many relation between courses and tags , and I wanted to use the sync method with the Select2 package to attach and deattach tags from courses in a convenient way but I can not find a way to set the selected values of the Select2 while using ajax data. If anyone can provide a simple guide guide on how to do this it would be really appreciated :D.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, I just had to avoid using Form generators

```
<select name="tags" id="tag_list" class="form-control" multiple>
   @foreach ($course->tags as $tag)
      <option value="{{ $tag->id }}" selected>{{ $tag->name }}</option> 
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: The problem is that when you use ajax data with Select2 it removes all written options and re-writes them with the json response from the ajax request

Comment: I would like to use this approach too but the problem right now is that the templateResult
and
templateSelection return undefined : undefined 
do you have any idea on how to write the option tag so that Select2 can extract the needed data?

Comment: I didn't use a custom template before. But according to select2 docs, it should be the same. Check [link](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) for the ajax example with a pre-selected option, don't forget to check the source code for the template. I will also try to test it later

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a Ajax request, the  control is not filled with data.
In Select2 v.4 >, if you don't want to follow the what suggested by official docs you can use something like this JS function to set initial value

```
function initSelect2(control, key, value){
    var data = {
        id: key,
        text: value
    };
    var initOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
    control.append(initOption);
    control.val(value).trigger('change');
}
```

Then call

```
initSelect2( $('#tags'), '{{ $tag->id }}', '{{ $tag->name }}');
```

to set default/initial value